# Update Quantity in shopping cart with dropdownlist onchange event in ListView and change another textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, shopping-cart

I have a shopping cart solution written with ASP.NET. In Cart Web Page I have a list view for products and each item has a `DropDownList` for quantity. I want to update total price of each item when user change quantity.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="fone">
        <%# Eval("Total")%>
      </td>
        <td class="ftwo">
          <asp:DropDownList ID="lstCount" runat="server"  >
            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5" />
          </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
      <td class="ffour">
        <%# Eval("Price")%>
      </td>
```

I wrote this jQuery code to update the total price for each row:

```
$('.ftwo').change(function(){
  var price=$(this).closest('tr').find('.fone').html();
  var quantity =$(this).val();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.ffour').html(price * quantity);
});
```

It works for me. The problem is that I want to update another `<td>` in another table:

```
 <table class="rtl white">
  <tbody>
     <tr class="first">
     <td class="first">
         <asp:Literal ID="txtSumPrice" runat="server" ></asp:Literal></td>
     </tr>
```

How do can I do this?

I write ASP.NET code to show `SumPrice` in `pageLoad`, but I wish to update `txtSumPrice` when user changes quantity in one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the change event callback function, compute the total accumulated value and set it to the `txtSumPrice` field

```
$('.ftwo').on('change',function(){
   var price=$(this).closest('tr').find('.fone').html();
   var quantity =$(this).val();
   $(this).closest('tr').find('.ffour').html(price * quantity);
   var totalPrice=parseFloat($('span#txtSumPrice').val())+ parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.ffour').text());
   $('span#txtSumPrice').val( totalPrice);
});
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: i use:    var totalPrice = quantity * (parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.ffour').text()) - parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.fthree').text()));
        $('#txtSumPrice').val(totalPrice);

Comment: it's work for textbox.but problem is ffour and fthree are in a listview . i want to sum all ffour and fthree values . how to do it?

Comment: Could you post the html dom structure thats produced at the browsers end, because this asp.net code is difficult to manage with jquery

Comment: can i send to you web page source ? can i send private messages to you?

Comment: @user3234297: not required, you can create a jsfiddle  and add the relevant code there. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: my asp.net code calculate sumprice and sumdiscount and sumtotal in pageload . problem is when user change quantity.

Comment: @user3234297: i dont get it, there isnt any element in the with ids as `txtSumPrice` ,`txtSumDiscount` & `txtTotal` in the jsfiddle which you have shared. if these things are calculated by your code behind file, then what are you expecting from the  jquery code ???

Comment: i want to change SumPrice and etc when user change quantity value without postback .

Comment: your code is ok but has some problem in calculate . refer to http://jsfiddle.net/MLsAu/13/ to and change quantity value to see problem in calculate

Comment: yeah i got it, but  the field holding sum price,discount and the actual total price arent present in the jsfiddle. you  have removed them thats why the values under those fields are not changing when dropdown is changed.

Comment: wrong in calculate . in this example , when user change first row quantity to 1, sum price should be 10000 . but show 5000 .

Comment: @user3234297: yeah now i got it . sorry buddy my mistake. i've corrected my mistake, here you go, i have corrected it.http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/MLsAu/39/